# How to get cookies from Ajax / xmlhttprequest call's response

Tags: ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-10, setcookie

My application is making a network call using **xmlHttpRequest**. In the response i am getting **Set-Cookie** header (verified with fiddler). I need to access these cookies from javasript. I tried with `XmlHttpRequest.getAllResponseHeaders()`, it is returning all headers except **Set-Cookie**.

Is there a way to access these cookies from javascript? If yes, please provide some example.

My application is running on Webbrowser control (IE10), Windows Phone 8.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mine's only returning three headers and my `Set-Cookie` header is clearly visible in chrome dev tools. Same problem here.

Answer (score 0):

While awaiting a more specific answer, you can instead send all the cookies set from the server through a `post` response, then set it locally, as so (using jQuery to make it easier):

```
// Client
var cookie;
$.post('example.com',{'stuff':'data'},function(data){
    cookie = data;
});

// Server
if(isset($_POST['stuff'])) echo WhateverTheCookieWouldBe;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually cookies can be accessed via

```
document.cookie // this will return a string contains all cookie values separated by semicolon
```

This is actually not true since because of the `async` nature of request

```
// Client
var cookie;
$.post('example.com',{'stuff':'data'},function(data){
    cookie = data; 
});

alert(cookie); // undefined
```